# How to get and set the Component content before a Component loads in Tridion

Tags: event-system, tom.net

In order to create a new Component, I will go to the Folder level and select "Create New Component" from ribbon toolbar.

Before the Component completely loads, I want to set some default content for this Component.

I am trying through the following event handler:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, LoadEventArgs>(LoadComponentData, 
                                                EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

And then:

```
private void LoadComponentData(Component component, LoadEventArgs args, EventPhases phases)
{
    Logger.WriteWarning("Component Title" + component.Title, ErrorCode.GENERAL);
    Logger.WriteWarning("Component Title" + component.Content, ErrorCode.GENERAL);
}
```

I am getting an empty value for `component.Content`, is there any other way to set/get the Component content for newly created Components?

What I require is, before this newly created Component completely loads to the author, I would like to set some default value for this Component. (Note: I am explicitly saying for the newly created Component, not when opening an existing one).

I can't use the Default Data from the Schema since I want to set multiple values in a multiple value field, and via the Schema I can only set a single value.

Answer (score 3):

The Event that you're subscribing to, `LoadEventArgs`, is correct.  However, you should subscribe to the `Initiated` Phase, not the `TransactionCommitted` Phase as you have.

Here is where you can get more info about Event Phases (login required): http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_FCA7A7E543ED4470BFB8B697CB6F8C3C

Comment: Even in Initiated Phase also, i am not getting any content for newly creating component. i need to get the value for component.Content.

Comment: I actually think the `LoadEventArgs` is not correct, the phase is probably irrelevant here (although I would suggest `EventPhases.Processed` or `EventPhases.TransactionCommitted`). I never tried this event on a Component, so can't be 100% sure unfortunately.

Comment: I just looked at a production piece of code we have that sets default Page Metadata Schema with some values when creating a new page.  We used this: EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, LoadEventArgs>(SetPageMetadata, EventPhases.Processed);

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [my answer here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/eventsystem-call-for-page-load-fires-twice/3248/#3248) there are a few things you have to keep in mind. You can subscribe to the `LoadEventArgs` and `EventPhases.Processed` or `EventPhases.TransactionCommitted`, but you have to be aware that this event can be called multiple times.

I gather you want to set default values on a newly created Component, so the first check you should do in your code is see if this is a new Component. You can do that with the condition `component.Id == TcmUri.UriNull`.

But you also need to see in the `Environment.StackTrace` through which Method you are called. Since as mentioned this event is called multiple times and the one you need is the one called by `CoreServiceBase.GetDefaultData`. My solution in SDL Tridion 2013 would be as follows (in 2011 it might need to be different):

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private static void LoadComponentData(Component component, LoadEventArgs args, EventPhases phases)
{
    // only react on new Components
    if (component.Id == TcmUri.UriNull) 
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        foreach (var frame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
        {
            // build Class.Method
            MethodBase method = frame.GetMethod();
            string name = method.ReflectedType.Name + "." + method.Name;

            // only trigger on CoreServiceBase.GetDefaultData, not on CoreServiceBase.Create (which is the second call)
            if (name.Equals("CoreServiceBase.GetDefaultData")) break;
            if (name.Equals("CoreServiceBase.Create")) return;
        }

        // add your code to set the field values here
        // note: you might need to check if the Schema of the Component is already set
        // if that is not done, then this isn't the right event to try and set default data

    }
}
```

A different approach could be to use the `GetInstanceDataEventArgs` event, that is the one called for setting the default data in the Component from its Schema.

Comment: how to set the field values here as i am getting empty value for component.Content

Comment: @Target see the note in my code, you might need to check if the Schema of the Component is already set. As you can see in the answer I mentioned, I used this approach to set a Metadata Schema on a Page and fill it with default data, but for a Component I suggest you investigate the `GetInstanceDataEventArgs` event, if your Component doesn't have a Schema set yet in the `LoadEventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using default value in the Schema for the component, if you have Static default values for the fields.

Else if there is some business logic involved to evaluate the values of the component fields. 
you must use the Event System to fill the fields. Please refer to the @Nickoli's answar.

also, I suggest to Re-Start the Tridion CM to take the Event System effect.

Comment: But we can set only one default value for schema field.Is there any other settings to set multiple default value.

Comment: yes, default value is always one. If you want so set one value from many, follow Nick's answar.

Comment: i am getting the empty value for component content even in initiated phase also. when i can get the complete content for the component.

Comment: please re-check you subscribed to the "Initiated" Phase, configured the Event Handler rightly and re-started the Tridion Content Manger.