# Value cannot be null, Parameter name: rootElement

Tags: 2013, cme

I am getting an error when trying to create and save a page in the Home structure Group of a publication. What does this error mean?

Update: We have a metadata schema for the pages in this publication associated with a particular page template and a mandatory field called "default url" in the metadata schema. This field has a default value of "/" and is populated with the page path on save. This is done using event handler. When a page is saved with default template and saved with our page template for the second time, there is no problem. However, if we use the page template on the first save, the error appears and the default url is not getting populated.

Comment: Could you please post the entire error, including stack trace for event log?

Comment: What events are you subscribing to exactly? If using a Page Load event, please see the answer I have given here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/eventsystem-call-for-page-load-fires-twice/3248#3248

Answer (score 2):

In your templates, check for the parameter schema associated and verify that a specific mandatory value is not empty or null. It may happen in case when you import templates from one environment to another and the item on which template have a dependency (may be a category/keyword or a component link ) has not been imported.
You can see parameters in a template either in template builder or in the source tab of the template.

The same scenario applies for the page as well.

Comment: Also metadata should be checked

Comment: Pankaj, We are not passing any parameters. And just noticed and updated, happens in the all the environments and due to a particular reason which I have updated in the question

Comment: @user978511: I have a feeling metadata is the problem for me too because of the update in my question. Could you be more specific as of what to check?

Answer (score 1):

I feel the problem with you event handler. The exception you get is thrown because `Page.Metadata` is empty during creation. I can imagine that your event handler is trying to look up path of the page, but, depending on what way it trying to get data, the data might not yet be there, as this is new page and some properties are only being set after it's actually created, `Page.Path` is one of them.

Your event handler is probably trying to read `Page.Path` and generate XML, but as it is `null` it fails. You probably have this entire block somewhere in try-catch statement and can't even see if your event handler failed.

For future questions, please include entire stack trace and describe your process straightaway, otherwise no one will help you.